# Ordenar arquivos em shell

Tags: shell-script

Sou iniciante em programação e estou preso em um código aqui.

Através de shell tenho que buscar dentro de diretórios e sub diretórios todos os arquivos que sejam do formato `.py` e tenham a livraria `datetime` incluída. E depois disso tenho mostrar o maior arquivo dessa lista. As primeiras duas partes saíram, mas não tenho ideia de como mostrar o maior arquivo deles:

```
find . -name '*.py' -type f exec -grep "import datetime" {} -lirw \;
```

Esse código está funcionando bem para buscar todos os arquivos python que tenham a livraria `datetime`.

Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Comando:

```
find . -name '*.py' -type f | xargs du -a | sort -n -r | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar:

```
find . -iname '*.py' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lS
```

Completando:

```
find . -iname "*.py" -exec sh -c 'procura=$(grep "SHAZAM" {}); if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo {};fi' \; | xargs ls -lS
```

Procura pelos arquivos `.py` e execute o seguinte script: Se achar a string nesse arquivo imprima o nome dele, depois passe como entrada padrão para o `ls -lhS` que ordena pelo tamanho do arquivo e imprime em alto nível.